# How to get datetime without time with t-sql?

Tags: sql, t-sql, sybase

Suppose I have variable as:

```
declare @dt datetime
declare @d datetime
set @dt = getdate()
```

then I want to get date from @dt and assign it to @d. For example, if @dt='2014-07-02 2:30:22'
@t should be @d = '2014-07-02 00:00:00'

data type for @d should be same datetime, not varchar.

Answer (score 1):

You could cast it to `DATE` datatype

```
SELECT CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
```

Comment: Thanks, but this return type is date, not datetime.